Force using origin in BASE url when using Vite's development server
I have a Vite/Vue SSR server for template rendering behind a Django server. I.e. Django calls node, gets html back, and sends it back to the browser. I encountered a problem with Vite's dev server in that it doesn't respect a full BASE url like https://bar.com/foo/ (it strips out the origin part, which is documented behavior). Without the origin part, however, the generated html and other assets contain urls that the browser treats as relative to the origin of the Django server, which obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to force Vite to include the origin in the BASE url?
So far, I've been able to workaround this issue by:

Add a <base> tag to index.html:

<base href="http://localhost:5173/" />

Which worked for most requests, except for /static/@vite/client. For this, I also had to configure Django to redirect this path to the Vite dev server:
def vite_redirect(request):
    return redirect('http://localhost:5173/static/@vite/client')

urlpatterns = [
    path('static/@vite/client', vite_redirect),
    ...
]

This works, but I do see that the vite client now connects to the HMR server twice, once when it's loaded on the localhost:8000 origin, and then again when it's loaded on the localhost:5173 origin:
[vite] connecting... client:495:8
[vite] connected. client:614:14
[vite] connecting... client:495:8
[vite] connected. client:614:14


I got this working by adding a <base> tag, taking special care to place it right after the <head> tag. Otherwise, Vite inserted its client script tag before the <base> tag, but the <base> tag only applies to elements that come after it. There's an explicit warning to keep this in mind in the MDN docs for <base>:

Warning: A <base> element must have an href attribute, a target
attribute, or both. If at least one of these attributes are specified,
the <base> element must come before other elements with attribute
values that are URLs, such as a <link>'s href attribute.

To add the <base> tag before Vite's client script tag, I used a Vite transformIndexHtml plugin:
plugins: [
  vue(),
  {
    name: 'vite-client-script-transform',
    transformIndexHtml(html: string) {
      return html.replace(
        '<head>', 
        `<head><base href="http://localhost:5173" />`,
      )
    }
  }        
],

